# Issue With Telerik Input Controls

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, telerik, telerik-radinput

I have a shared user control.  This UC is in one page and everything works fine.  In the second page, the RadTextBox client-API get_value() method reports "", when it has a legitimate value.  There is very little javascript on that page, and it's not targeting textboxes; it's in a page with 6 tabs.  The controls work fine; I have RadCombo's and the drop downs work as you would expect.  But no text, no selected value, nothing is being reported (I have a script to check if the page is an empty form).  How do I even debug this to figure out what is going on, and why the value isn't being reported?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a duplicate method name in a user control,copied twice, so that's why it was bombing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to start with debugging your js code and see whether the telerik inputs' client objects are valid in your context. If so, rhe methods from their client API should return the values set from the end user.